# How to get Cisco VPN connection status in Batch for further processing

Tags: batch-file, vpn, cisco

I want to check whether I am connected to a Cisco VPN in a batch script. What I am currently trying is this:

```
.\vpnclient.exe | Findstr 'Connected'
```

This does kind of work: Calling `vpnclient.exe` opens Cisco's cli tool, then the `Findstr` command runs correctly. What I cannot get to work is: How do I then programmatically exit that tool and proceed? I can then manually exit the tool, but that is not really the idea of automation.

I have tried simply putting `exit` in the the next line, or `echo exit | vpnclient.exe | Findstr 'Connected'`, `.\vpnclient.exe | Findstr 'Connected' | exit`, `exit | .\vpnclient.exe | Findstr 'Connected'`.

None of those exited the tool, the execution of the script simply halts. Sometimes, I can't even exit it manually anymore and have to open a new window.

Other questions on stackoverflow did not help, no one there seems to try to then programmatically exit and proceed.

How can I either programmatically exit Cisco's cli tool or check the connection status in another way, so I can proceed execution depending on the connection status?

Edit: `(echo Y|vpnclient.exe) | Findstr "Connected"` takes me into the cli tool, but I still have to exit it manually via ctrl + c, which is non-usable. I feel like Cisco's tool has some weird behavior here, or am I wrong about this?

Comment: Is `vpnclient.exe /?` helpful?

Comment: After some googling, `(echo Y|vpnclient.exe) | Findstr "Connected" might work.

Comment: @stephan, the vpnclient has no corresponding commands. Your proposed solution looked promising, but sadly, the same thing happens: The string is found, but processing does not proceed and the script is stuck in the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sites and threads I had previously found all recommended simply calling `.\vpnclient.exe` to get the connection status. This leads to the behavior described in the question.

Turns out, the VPN client has a command called `status`, which does exactly what one would expect. So, what works is:

```
.\vpnclient.exe status | Findstr "Connected"
echo %errorlevel%
```

Simple as that. Why this is not recommended (or well-documented) more often I do not know.